# why is the live data observe method not called?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am using Room and livedata in my android app but I can not get data inside of livedata and I try every thing . the last way was using observe method that gives me a list but this method is not called, how can I solve this?

this is my Dao interface

```
@Dao
public interface QuestionTemplateDao {

    @Query("SELECT question_template_table.ID,question_template_table.Text,question_template_table.FieldNo from question_template_table where question_template_table.FieldNo = :fieldNO")
    LiveData<List<QuestionTemplate>> getTemplate(int fieldNO);

}
```

and this is my Repo

```
public LiveData<List<QuestionTemplate>> getmAllQuestionTemplates(int field) {
        if(questionTemplateDao==null)
            questionTemplateDao=db.questionTemplateDao();
        mQuestionTemplates=questionTemplateDao.getTemplate(field);
        return mQuestionTemplates;
    }
```

and this is viewModel

```
templateLiveData = mRepository.getmAllQuestionTemplates(selectedField);
        templateList = new ArrayList<>();
        templateLiveData.observe(activity, new Observer<List<QuestionTemplate>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<QuestionTemplate> questionTemplates) {
                Log.e("onChanged","onChanged");
                if (questionTemplates != null) {
                    templateList.addAll(questionTemplates);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use directly like this in **`ViewModel`**:

```
templateList = new ArrayList<>();
mRepository
    .getmAllQuestionTemplates(selectedField)
    .observe(activity, new Observer<List<QuestionTemplate>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<QuestionTemplate> questionTemplates) {
            Log.e("onChanged","onChanged");
            if (questionTemplates != null) {
                templateList.addAll(questionTemplates);
            }
        }
    });
```

No need to take new object of `LiveData` in `ViewModel`, you can also directly observe from that `LiveData` returned to you.

---

**Edit:**

Check another workaround,

Your DAO will be like:

```
@Dao
public interface QuestionTemplateDao {

    @Query("SELECT question_template_table.ID,question_template_table.Text,question_template_table.FieldNo from question_template_table where question_template_table.FieldNo = :fieldNO")
    List<QuestionTemplate> getTemplate(int fieldNO);

}
```

Your repository,

```
public void getmAllQuestionTemplates(int field, MutableLiveData<List<QuestionTemplate>> liveData) {
    if(questionTemplateDao==null)
        questionTemplateDao=db.questionTemplateDao();
    liveData.setValue(questionTemplateDao.getTemplate(field));
}
```

Your ViewModel,

```
mRepository.getmAllQuestionTemplates(selectedField, (MutableLiveData<List<QuestionTemplate>>) templateLiveData);
templateList = new ArrayList<>();
templateLiveData.observe(activity, new Observer<List<QuestionTemplate>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<QuestionTemplate> questionTemplates) {
            Log.e("onChanged","onChanged");
            if (questionTemplates != null) {
                templateList.addAll(questionTemplates);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @faezesaghafi you won't get notified directly through from `LiveData` unless you have some change of data in db.

Comment: :((( so How can I get  simple list inside of livedata? I dont want to use allowMainThreadQueries()

Comment: You can simply get list from dao and manually call `setValue()` on `LiveData` in repository to be observe `LiveData` in view model. let me know if confused, i'll edit answer. @faezesaghafi

Comment: can you show me "simply get list from dao and manually call setValue()" , please?

Comment: @faezesaghafi please check answer now, take your `templateLiveData` as `MutableLiveData` if you fail to cast it from `LiveData`.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time... oh my GOD:(((

Comment: Yes or you can call it from new thread. second is recommended way.

Comment: THANK YOU ... I love you... really ... I mean it :-*  :-*  :-*

Comment: happy coding :)